# Convergence for $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^a}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Study the convergence of: $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n^a}$$ where $a \gt 0$

I tried a comparison with the harmonic series $1/n^a$ but doesn't really seem to work, since the resulting limit would yield me 0, which doesn't help me. I'm guessing my series should converge for $a \ge 1$ and diverge otherwise, but I'm not sure on how to prove this.

Answer (score 8):

Write it as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^a(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}$. Then compare with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n^{a+1/2}}$.

Comment: Ah, so that would make it divergent for $a \le 1/2$ and convergent for $a \gt 1/2$ Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it would diverge for $a\leq 1/2$ and converge for $a>1/2$. Right!!